# Как правильно делать на php проверку страницы на которой находишься

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Сайт на wordpress+woocommerce. Мне нужно проверить на какой странице нахожусь и выполнить определенные действия исходя из нее. Подскажите как правильно делать на php проверку страницы на которой находишься, чтобы само условие не выводилось на экран?
Пишу так:

```
if(the_title()!="Оформление") { echo "yes!"; }
```

на выходе `Оформлениеyes!`
Делаю так

```
<?php is_checkout() ? wp_title(''); ?>
```

ничего не выводится...
Частично решено с помощью такой записи:

```
if(the_title('','',false)=="Оформление") {...}
```

Comment: Для начала необходимо прочитать [документацию](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), тогда, возможно, и вопросы все отпадут. И как-то проверять страницу по ее заголовку не есть хорошо - а что если вы решите заголовок изменить? Менять все в коде?

Comment: @BOPOH так я же и пишу, что через `title` не вариант и прошу подсказать как правильно! думал через вот такую проверку прокатит `is_checkout()`,но не прокатывает..

Comment: вы пишите что не вариант, т.к. происходит вывод, я показал доки, где написано как убрать его. Т.е. по идее вас должен устроить такой вариант, поэтому я дополнительно написал, что так делать не стоит. Судя по документации `is_checkout` он делает то, что вам надо, только синтаксис разве такой должен быть? Разве не `some_condition ? if_true : if_else;`

Comment: @BOPOH т.е. имеете ввиду так `if(is_checkout()) ? echo '<p>checkout</p>' : echo '<p>cart</p>';` ?
но возникает ошибка - пустую страницу показывает..

Comment: Нет, либо `if(is_checkout()) { echo 'yes'; } else { echo 'no'; }`, либо `echo (is_checkout() ? 'yes' : 'no');` Если скажет 'no', значит как-то не так делали страницу оформления заказа (с woo... не работал, сужу по докам)

Comment: @BOPOH говорит ноу. страница оформления сделана правильно, т.к. в хлебных крошках на этой же странице `is_checkout()` воспринимает. проблема в другом - на это странице есть шорткод корзины, внутри которого я и хочу условие проверить - он скорее всего выполняется на странице `.php` шаблона, вот и `is_checkout()` поэтому не воспринимает. скорее всего другого решения не существует, чем я записал выше